# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput audio/video synchronization

Tags: video, avfoundation

I have written a small app to capture audio and video using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, which has been working great. It is used to automatically collect experimental data over many days, turning on occasionally to record 10-15 seconds at a time.

But in analyzing the data, we have identified that there seems to be some drift in the audio and video synchronization. To help test this, we setup a blink LED combined with a tone and recorded it for short segments over several days. By the fifth day, the audio developed a delay of approximately ~250ms (not huge, but noticeable when watching). The image below shows the data read back using the same `AVFoundation` libraries (to ensure there was not an issue decoding the media). The average intensity of the video is plotted (to show the LED flash) and the raw audio is plotted below.

[image: Plot highlighting delay]

This is somewhat mysterious, and I am hoping to try to figure out what could cause this so I can either fix it or work around it. My theories thus far are:

- A purely hardware problem (we use an NTSC dongle), where something about the digitization of the signal or the clock on the dongle has some sort of skew or drift. I don't know enough about the hardware side of things to investigate.
- A rounding issue having to do with the counting of frame durations for audio and video, where a slight offset accumulates over time. If this is the case, we could potentially calculate the expected offset and adjust for it.

I realize this is a bit of a corner case of `AVCaptureMovieFieldOutput` usage, but would value any feedback from others.

I doubt any of this is specific to the code, but tend to be more broad implementation details. The code closely mirrors standard movie capture examples from the AVFoundation documentation, with frame precise start times. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/nathanntg/video-capture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further analysis suggest that it was a specific flaw in the video capture hardware we used that has some sort of drift in its internal clock. Capturing from other hardware over several days did not exhibit the same increasing delay.

My current work around is that the increasing delay appears to be linear (~170ms per day), and hence can be well predicted.